# Reassigning strings involving pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, variable-assignment

This is a homework problem, and I believe it is a syntax problem.  I have a program with a method that uses arrays of chars to represent strings.  I'm trying to copy parts of the arrays into a temporary variable.  I pass in these variables:

```
int numbers[], char arr1[][20], char arr2[][20], int l, int r
```

and initialize/copy into the temporary variables:

```
char *temp1;
char *temp2;

temp1 = arr1[l];
temp2 = arr2[l];
```

This code compiles and I believe it works. The problem occurs when I try to assign the temporary variables to places in the array. I've tried both:

```
arr1[l] = temp1;
arr2[l] = temp2;
```

and

```
arr1[l] = &temp1;
arr2[l] = &temp2;
```

all of these result in the following error:

```
error: incompatible types in assignment
```

So obviously I'm not writing these statements correctly. Both are of type char(I don't know if that has anything to do with the problem). I don't know how I can fix this though. Could anyone please help?

Comment: You can't copy a C array by assignment operator. You need to memcpy() the contents from one side to another, or bury the array in a structure and use a stucture-copy.

Comment: Would strcpy() work as well?  If so, then should I, for example, be writing: strcpy(arr1[l], temp1); instead of: arr1[l] = temp1;?

Answer (score 2):

```
arr1[l]
```

`arr1[l]` is an array (a `char[20]`, specifically). Arrays are not modifiable lvalues, hence they are not assignable.

You need to copy the contents of the array pointed to by `temp` to `arr1[l]`. But, if you're trying to swap rows or something like that, you need to allocate some intermediate storage because

```
char *temp = arr2[l];
```

doesn't copy the contents, so a

```
memcpy(arr2[l], source, some_size);
```

would change the contents of what `temp` points to, the old contents of `arr2[l]` would be lost.